# Property '.....' not found on object of type '........'

Tags: objective-c

Im trying to build an app that calculates sales but im getting the error message ***Property '.....' not found on object of type 'ATSettings'***.

Comment: Does the ... Stand for something or is that the exact error message you are getting? Either way your code somewheres is looking for a property that doesn't exist.

Comment: it stands for each field, ie itemname , itemcost etc

Comment: Post the `ATSettings.h` file.

Comment: Any hope of seeing `ATsettings.m`?

Comment: @Tommy - why? The error has nothing to do with `ATsettings.m`.

Comment: @rmaddy the text given is clearly not the error being provided by Xcode; with others already handling the far-and-away most likely compiler case I thought it was worth getting a jump on the potential that the error is coming from the linker.

Comment: ATSettings.m added tommy. Im still getting error messages but not sure why?

Comment: @Dave Did my answer help? If not, please clarify exactly which lines of code are giving the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simple - you didn't import the `ATsettings.h` file in your `ViewController.m` file.

Add this line:

```
#import "ATsettings.h"
```

after the other imports in the `ViewController.m` file.